# How to tell if function is joint cdf or not?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a CDF given:

$$F_{XY} = 1-e^{-xy}$$ which is defined for $x,y \geq 0$ and is $0$ otherwise.

The task was to show, that ***it's not a joint cdf*** so I took the derivative two times:

\begin{align}
\frac{d^{2}}{dxdy}F_{XY}(x,y) &=\frac{d^{2}}{dydx}F_{XY}(x,y) = f_{XY}(x,y) \\
e^{-xy}(1-xy) &=  e^{-xy}(1-xy)
\end{align}

And got the same result for both sides, which show that it is actually a joint cdf...

Does anyone has an idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach shows nothing, just that partial derivatives commute (which happens quite often). You need to check the definition of a joint CDF.

$F(x,y)$ is a joint CDF if and only if:

(1) $0 \leq F(x,y) \leq 1$

(2) $F(x,y)$ is non-decreasing in x and non-decreasing in y

(3) $F(x,y)$ is right continuous in x and right continuous in y

(4) If $a<b,c<d$ then $F(b,d)-F(b,c)-F(a,d)+F(a,c) \geq 0$

(5) $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x,y) = 0$ for each y, $\lim_{y \to -\infty} F(x,y) = 0$ for each $x$

(6) $\lim_{x,y \to \infty} F(x,y) = 1$

See [these notes](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/notes_webpage.html) for more details, page 163.

As for how to fix your approach: The second mixed derivative is negative for $xy \geq 1$. You're claiming that a probability density function can be negative, which is nonsense. You should try to show how the conditions of the joint CDF are violated using this information.

In particular, look at condition 4 with $a,c=1$ and $b,d=2$. If this were a CDF, it would imply lying in the rectangle with corners $(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)$ is negative, which is impossible for a probability.

Comment: I see. I wished the script the prof gave us was as informative as this post. Thanks, Batman.